# how to modify non partitioned table in to partitioned one using hash partition

Tags: oracle, hash, partition

How to modify oracle non partitioned table in to partitioned one using hash partition? I am facing issue while running this partition statement :

```
alter table t1 modify partition by hash (id) partitions 8;
```

The error says

> ORA 14006 :Invalid partition name

Comment: Your code works for me. [Check out the demo on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8dabb733857c1892f18ee0386cdc9c68). So you'll need to post a reproducible test case if you want further help from us.

Comment: Yes you are right..Actually i have checked that in Oracle 12c which didnot worked. Then after you said, then i tried it in Oracle 19c  and it worked..Thanks for your help.That means I was using the correct syntax, only oracle version was the problem ..Thank you